# do_compile error on building docker

Tags: docker, yocto, lxc, openembedded

I am building docker in the latest version of yocto (morty), but the build is failing du to the following errors

```
ERROR: containerd-0.2.2+git0ac3cd1be170d180b2baed755e8f0da547ceb267-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
```

I am also getting some log data, which is as follows

```
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 8 static
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| /var/mshehery/Documents/git/poky/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/containerd/0.2.2+git0ac3cd1be170d180b2baed755e8f0da547ceb267-r0/git
| cd ctr && go build -ldflags "-w -extldflags -static -X github.com/docker/containerd.GitCommit=0ac3cd1be170d180b2baed755e8f0da547ceb267 " -tags "" -o ../bin/ctr
| cd containerd && go build -ldflags "-w -extldflags -static -X github.com/docker/containerd.GitCommit=0ac3cd1be170d180b2baed755e8f0da547ceb267 " -tags "" -o ../bin/containerd
| cd containerd-shim && go build -ldflags "-w -extldflags -static -X github.com/docker/containerd.GitCommit=0ac3cd1be170d180b2baed755e8f0da547ceb267 " -tags "" -o ../bin/containerd-shim
| # runtime/internal/sys
| compile: unknown architecture "i586"
| Makefile:58: recipe for target 'shim-static' failed
| make: *** [shim-static] Error 2
| make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| # runtime/internal/sys
| compile: unknown architecture "i586"
| Makefile:46: recipe for target 'client-static' failed
| make: *** [client-static] Error 2
| # runtime/internal/sys
| compile: unknown architecture "i586"
| Makefile:52: recipe for target 'daemon-static' failed
| make: *** [daemon-static] Error 2
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /var/mshehery/Documents/git/poky/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/containerd/0.2.2+git0ac3cd1be170d180b2baed755e8f0da547ceb267-r0/temp/log.do_compile.20684)
```

Apparently, there is some issue with containerd, the daemon to control runC. Can anyone suggest a fix here? I am using the meta-virtualization layer and it's dependencies for docker. All the layers are morty compatible.

Comment: Could you try to add `inherit go-osarchmap` to the containerd recipe? This is per

Comment: @Anders Still getting the same error.

Comment: Well, doing that you should get the architecture set to `386` instead of `i586`... Could you check for that?

Comment: @Anders Inheriting go-osarchmap is not setting the architecture to 386. I am getting the same error of unknown architecture. Isn't the i586 architecture supported in yocto 2.2?

Comment: Yocto supports it. The question is what go and containerd supports...

Answer (score 0):

Following is the update on my problem

The recipe specifies the following architecture as supported

```
do_compile() {
export GOARCH="${TARGET_ARCH}"
# supported amd64, 386, arm arm64
```

In order to remove the error and build containerd_git.bb, the target architecture needs to changed from i586 to the supported one. The architecture is specified in the poky/build/conf/local.conf file as follows

```
# You need to select a specific machine to target the build with. There are a selection
# of emulated machines available which can boot and run in the QEMU emulator:
#
#MACHINE ?= "qemuarm"
#MACHINE ?= "qemuarm64"
#MACHINE ?= "qemumips"
#MACHINE ?= "qemuppc"
#MACHINE ?= "qemux86"
#MACHINE ?= "qemux86-64"
#
# There are also the following hardware board target machines included for 
# demonstration purposes:
#
#MACHINE ?= "beaglebone"
#MACHINE ?= "genericx86"
#MACHINE ?= "genericx86-64"
#MACHINE ?= "mpc8315e-rdb"
#MACHINE ?= "edgerouter"
#
# This sets the default machine to be qemux86 if no other machine is selected:
MACHINE ??= "genericx86-64"
```

I was able to successfully build the recipe with the above setting.